# React Navigation: Use small header on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm presenting a view with a header as card with `ReactNavigation`.
The view looks fine on android but uses a large header on iOS which looks strange.
How can I use the smaller header that iOS apps use?

Here is a screenshot of the too large header:
[image]

Comment: That rather a thing that the operating system should handle.
AFAIK you can amend the actionBarSize on android, but it‘s not a good design strategy to port the native design from iOS to android.

When you do hybrid app development I would suggest a  design hybrid approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution for this:

It seems that setting altering the `headerStatusBarHeight` option to 0 helps to get the small header

```
 <Stack.Screen
  name="Screen1"
  component={Screen1}
  options={({navigation}) => ({
    headerStatusBarHeight: 0, //use this to get the small navbar on iOS
  })}
/>
```